# selection of tag ids

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have the HTML code here.

In browser, I can fetch each id using firebug like

```
document.querySelectorAll('section').item(0).id
```

that means if I make a variable

```
inputFields = this.evaluate(function() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('section');
});
```

So `inputFields` array should have all four sections having their ids. Later I can access each it using `inputFields.item(index).id` to point to any section id.

Here is my casper script:

```
casper.then(function(){
    var inputFields = this.evaluate(function(){
        return document.getElementsByTagName('section');
    });
    require("utils").dump(inputFields.item(1).id);
});
```

Please correct me if I am doing something wrong. I am getting the error:

```
error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'inputFields.item(1)')
#           TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'inputFields.item(1)')
```

I want to have an array of section id's.

Comment: Did my answer help, do you have any problems?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve DOM elements from the page context into casper context. Only primitive types like boolean, number, string, `[]` and `{}` are permitted. The quote from the [PhantomJS documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) goes like this:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine. Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!

You need to do a part of your work in the page context. Like only reducing the elements to an `id`:

```js
casper.then(function(){
    var inputFields = this.evaluate(function(){
        return Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByTagName('section'), function(sectionItem){
            return sectionItem.id;
        });
    });
    require("utils").dump(inputFields[1]);
});
```

Although, I don't think that the type `section` is an input field in your case. You probably mean input fields inside of a section.